# SUM with conditions in a query/importrange from another Google sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a table like this in spreadsheet A:

```
| title| total  | 
|----- |--------| 
| X1   | 2      | 
| Y    | 3      | 
| Z    | 4      | 
| X2   | 5      |
```

Since this spreadsheet A is constantly updated and is using other formulas, I need to export it to another sheet to work on.
I also need to sum the Total column if the Title column match a condition such as Regexp.
Result should be as:

```
| title| total  | 

|----- |--------| 

| X    | 7      | 

| Y    | 3      | 

| Z    | 4      |
```

Please advise on this case, I've been studying query with sumif formula but it does not support sum when condition is not matched.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include what the regular expression would have been to base these groups on. I assume your sample data is simplified, meaning it is not just based on the first character of each title right?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `SUMIFS()` with wildcard option. Use below formula-

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$5,$A$2:$A$5,D2 & "*")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

after you allow access try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({REGEXREPLACE(
 IMPORTRANGE("id", "sheetname!A2:A"), "\d+$", ), 
 IMPORTRANGE("id", "sheetname!B2:B")}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image]